# Do we need better tags?

Tags: discussion, tags, tagging

Since this site has started I feel that we have had too many pointless tags. Most of these tags only have one or two questions. An example of one of these tags is the [waking-up](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/waking-up) tag. There can't be more than three or four questions that could ever be asked about that topic without being a duplicate, and the ones that have already been asked have been put on hold as off-topic. We also have the [holidays](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/holidays) and the [christmas](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/christmas) tags which must be tag synonyms and the [animals](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/animals) and [pets](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pets) tags which are also very similar. I think that we have too many tags like the [waking-up](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/waking-up) tag, such as [vomit](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vomit), [screw-removal](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/screw-removal), [closet](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/closet), and [basement-cellar](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/basement-cellar). There are also 15 tags without any questions. I think that we need to create some tags that can cover a wider spectrum of questions. I also think that we need to be a bit more strict about the creation of tags.

Thoughts?

Comment: I do agree with you, but what about tag synonyms.

Comment: Non-used tags are removed automatically

Comment: @iliveunderawesomerock I think we need more moderation on that also, but that will come soon once we get moderators.

Comment: @ZachSaucier I know that, but I think we need to stop these types of tags from being created in the first place

Comment: @michaelpri Stopping tags being created is not a good thing at this point since the whole site is still in definition.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It may be that we need better tags, but those will come in time.  People will ask questions, appropriate tags will get attached to them, inappropriate tags will get removed from them, and we'll all get better.  Remember, editing is a key part of a SE site.

I, personally, think it's good to have more tags, because newcomers to the site are going to want to use them to get attention on their questions, and they're not always going to have the reputation to create tags of their own.  It's better to have more than less.